# force removal of file extension even if it is typed

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using the code below in my htaccess file that always sends the site to the www version and allows the file extension to be removed if php. However, if a visitor types the extension, it still shows it.

How do I remove the file extension even if the visitor types it?

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess. Try reading through the accepted answer and see if that works for you.

Comment: You need to redirect to the non-php version, like `^(.*?)(.php)?$`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.php$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

If you want the redirection to non-php version to only happen when the php actually exists, use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.php$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```